# how to make a new div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

okay so, I need to create a new div using jquery with the information of a first and last name that I loop from my array.. This is what I have so far, I was wondering if I could get some help on how to make it show up on my webpage. it needs to show up like:

```
hello firstname lastname 
hello firstname lastname
hello firstname lastname
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

```
function names() {
         var firstAndLast = [
              {name: "jane", surname: "doe"},
              {name: "john", surname: "leg"},
              {name: "hunny", surname: "bun"}

            ];

        var div = $("#output");
            for (var i=0; i < firstAndLast.length; i++) {

        }

          var div1 = $("<div>").html("Hello name surname");
                 $("#names").append(div1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost there. The main issue is that you need to put the line of jQuery which creates the `div` and appends it *within* the `for` loop. In addition you can retrieve the `name` and `surname` from the objects in the array using the `i` variable to access them by index:

```
var $output = $("#output");
for (var i = 0; i < firstAndLast.length; i++) {
  var div1 = $("<div>").html(`Hello ${firstAndLast[i].name} ${firstAndLast[i].surname}`);
  $output.append(div1);
}
```

That being said, the most performant way to do this would be to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build an array of HTML strings which you only append to the DOM once:

```js
function names() {
  let firstAndLast = [
    { name: "jane", surname: "doe" }, 
    { name: "john", surname: "leg" }, 
    { name: "hunny", surname: "bun" }
  ]; 

  let html = firstAndLast.map(o => `<div>Hello ${o.name} ${o.surname}</div>`);
  $("#output").append(html);
}

names();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: oh my GOD, thank you so much! I was sitting here for hours!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
function names() {
  var firstAndLast = [{
      name: "jane",
      surname: "doe"
    },
    {
      name: "john",
      surname: "leg"
    },
    {
      name: "hunny",
      surname: "bun"
    }

  ];


  let _data = firstAndLast.reduce((acc, {
    name,
    surname
  }) => {

    acc += `hello <span>${name}</span> <span>${surname}</span><br>`
    return acc;
  }, "")


  $("#output").html(_data);

}

names()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">
</div>
```